# Magento disable products with no images

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am trying to disable a lot of products that do not have images in my Magento installation.

The following SQL query is supposed to get all products with no images but I need a way to set all products with no images to status disabled?

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity
            ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = talog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id 
   WHERE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value is NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for Kode:

```
-- here you set every one as DISABLED (id 2)
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 2 
-- here you are change just the attribute STATUS
WHERE attribute_id = 4
    -- here you are looking for the products that match your criteria
    AND entity_id IN (
        -- your original search
        SELECT entity_id 
        FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id 
        WHERE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value is NULL
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this for magento 2.2.3

```
update catalog_product_entity_int m
left join eav_attribute a on a.entity_type_id = 4 and a.attribute_id = m.attribute_id
set value = 2
where
  a.attribute_code = 'status'
  and m.entity_id in
    (
      select m.entity_id
      from catalog_product_entity m
      left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity a
        on a.entity_id = m.entity_id
      where a.value_id is null
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will obviously apply to any other attribute, so just change the code as necessary.

```
enabled = 1
disabled = 2

UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int cpei, catalog_product_entity cpe
SET cpei.value = "2"
WHERE cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id
AND cpe.sku LIKE '%SKU%'
AND cpei.attribute_id = 273
```

Also you can refer detail [Document link](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/fast-bulk-product-status-change-with-magento/)

let me know if i can help you further

Comment: I'm still not sure what the query would be and I don't want to try as I will most likely mess the db up

Comment: if possible take backup first then try :(

Comment: @KodeMatt you would be insane to do this on production, this is why you have a development build.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified it slightly and this worked for me

Removed  *WHERE attribute_id = 4* and updated *SELECT entity_id  to SELECT catalog_product_entity.entity_id*

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 2 
WHERE entity_id IN(
        SELECT catalog_product_entity.entity_id 
        FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id 
        WHERE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value is NULL
    );
```